# Is there a way to change LaTeX preview output size or font size in sympy

Tags: python-3.x, image, latex, sympy, discord.py

I am making a discord bot with discord.py. Currently, I'm working on a LaTeX printer with sympy.
I have the code:

```
  @commands.command(name="latex",
                      aliases=["tex", "tx"])
    async def texPrt(self, ctx, *, text):
        Funcs.command_exec(ctx)
        expre = sympify(text, evaluate=False)
        preview(expre, viewer="file", filename="output.png")
        await ctx.send(file=discord.File(f"./output.png", filename="LaTeX_output.png"))
```

This takes the equation that the user enters and outputs a png image:
[image]

The only issue is that the image that comes out is very small and low resolution. Is there a way to make it render the image larger and increase the font size.
Also if possible I would like to change the background colour to be similar to discord, but that's not the priority.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the density parameter in `dvioptions`:

> preview(expr, viewer="file", filename="output.png", dvioptions=['-D','1200'])

Comment: is there any way to adjust the size. Changing the value either up or down from 1200 to 600 or 2400 doesn't appear to do anything. @audiomason